# Remove small layer between bottom navigation and Floating action button?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-bottomnav

I added Bottom navigation with centered Floating Action button but there is small layer that behinds the bottom navigation and floating action button. How can i Remove small layer between bottom navigation and Floating action button?

[image: img]

> this is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomAppBar"/>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"/>
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom background drawable like below.

nav_bg_transparent.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:shape="rectangle" >

  <solid android:color="#00000000" />
```

And set it to `BottomNavigationView` like

```
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bg_transparent" 
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"/>
```